# How much Multitouch does my computer support?

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, multi-touch

I've got a Dell notebook at work, but I don't know much about which model it is, except that it is a XPS. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it.

Now, I know, that the Monitor and the Touchpad have some kind of Multitouch support, but I don't know much more. The touchpad and the monitor supports up to three fingers. As far as I can tell, pinch gestures are only used for 2 fingers on the touchpad and 3 fingers on the monitor.

xinput gives me this:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
```

I would like to know more specific, which gestures are supported by the hardware and the driver. Like, if I start developing multitouch stuff, what can I expect from my hardware? How many fingers do touchpad and monitor support? Which gestures can be used by an application?

Is there an easy way to find out?